# How to use the concept of activation context in .NET to load unmanaged dlls?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, activation-context-api

After some help and reading, I am sure the concept activation context can be used to solve my problem. In my application, I have to load an unmanaged dll `c.dll` by another managed dll `b.dll`, which is loaded by `a.dll`, which is loaded by `app.exe`. The sequence is that

```
app.exe -> a.dll (managed) -> b.dll (managed) -> c.dll (unmanaged)
```

I have the source of `a.dll` and `b.dll`, but `app.exe` and `c.dll` belongs to the third party. Now, regardless of whether `a.exe` loads other versions of `c.dll` or not, I have to load my own `c.dll` (my `c.dll` resides in a different folder with that carried by `a.exe` installation).

I used `LoadLibraryEx`, but that app.exe have loaded a different of c.dll before I can load my own c.dll. These two c.dll are same name with different versions. Since a different version of c.dll has been loaded, when I called LoadLibraryEx, my c.dll won't be loaded. I need a solution to solve this problem.

How does the concept *activation context* can be migrated to the .NET environment to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by activation context.

If you want to load an unmanaged DLL in a managed environment you need to do so via pInvoke:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);
```

Also, you will need to free the handle stored in the `IntPtr` returned by `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: yes, I used `LoadLibraryEx`, but that `app.exe` have loaded a different of `c.dll` before I can  load my own `c.dll`. These two `c.dll` are same name with different versions. Since a different version of `c.dll` has been loaded, when I called `LoadLibraryEx`, my `c.dll` won't be loaded. I need a solution to solve this problem.

Comment: `LoadLibraryEx` takes the path of the dll as a parameter so the handle returned should be to that particolar version identified by the path. You can load as amny dll versions as you want using different paths

Comment: @MarcoBeninca No, bro. you are wrong. you can write the codes and see the result. If you have loaded `a.dll` by `LoadLibraryEx`, it will return `NULL` if you attempt to load another different version but same name `a.dll` by calling `LoadLibraryEx` again.

Comment: @Lucas the solution is to use the old version then I guess...

Comment: `LoadLibrary` cannot load the same name dll. I tried, If 1. GetCurrentDirectory 2. SetCurrentDirectory(path1) 3, m1 = LoadLibary(libcef.dll) 4, setcurrentdirectory(path2) 5, m2 = LoadLibrary(libcef.dll) 6. restore the old current path for this process. m1 equals m2

Comment: @Lucas a more complicated solution but maybe defenetive could be to write different applications wchich then can communicate via a WCF service... this way any app is responsible to load a specific version of the dll

Comment: @MarcoBeninca yes, this idea is what I am thinking. the out-of-process model is useful in this problem. Createing a helper process, using that process to load my library, then communicate by some IPC mechanism.